# Dynamic Component Attributes of Arc's in Sketchup

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have a 3 point arc in my drawing. The dynamic attributes provided in standard are the same as for rectangles. Is there a way to define the 3 points as attributes to be able to change them dynamically afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [AttributeDictionary](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/attributedictionary) that are attached to every `Entity` and `Model` to store custom attributes.

```
dictname = "TestDictionary"
key = "arcs"
value = ["x", "y", "z"]
model = Sketchup.active_model
model.set_attribute dictname, key, value

dict = model.attribute_dictionary dictname
arcs = dict[key]

// or

arcs = model.get_attribute dictname, key
```